# External style sheet not updating in Chrome 74, but other files do

Tags: css, google-chrome, reload

I'm building a site in Chrome 74 using Notepad++ and XAMPP on localhost.

I have an `index.php` main file and an external style sheet `index.css`.
It is connected to the main file like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">`

After making a few updates to `index.css` I couldn't get Chrome to view them. Originally I thought my css was wrong. But after pressing F12 in Chrome and looking at `Sources` and checking the `index.css` file I saw that the changes I had written weren't there.

The changes have been saved in Notepad++, browser page has been refreshed. I even looked at `index.css` using good old regular notepad just to be sure.

I have also tried restarting the browser, restarting XAMPP and then restarting my computer. Still the same.

The interesting thing is, changes made to `index.php` are being updated successfully. It's solely the changes to `index.css` that aren't. It's as if Chrome does not reload `index.css` but keeps an old version of it.

It has happened to me before, but last time the problem sort of just went away after a while and Chrome started updating `index.css`. Now I want to know why it happens.

Does anyone know why Chrome does this? Help much appreciated :)

To be clear: As of the moment, no changes made to `index.css` is being loaded by Chrome. Even stuff like `body { background-color:red; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is being cached: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Usually, with the default configurations, dynamic pages (.php) are not cached and static files (.css, .js, etc.) are cached.

You can:

- Reload the page while pressing the shift ( ⇧ ) key
- Clear caché and then reload
- Implement a caché strategy for development

Comment: Clearing the cache worked, but I'm interesting in caché strategy. What does that mean?

Comment: Caching is good, as it avoids lot of innecesary data transmission, but it is an annoyance while developing.

So you can have different configurations in development and production, like no caché in development and a long caché expire in production. You can complicate it as much as needed (cache external libraries - if any - and not cache your files).

Example: In node.js, it's a convention use a NODE_ENV variable in the production environment. Some frameworks/libraries optimize depending on that.

However, I don't use your stack (XAMPP), so I can't give you details in your case.